# Why exit is not break php script?

Tags: php

I have such problem. On my system `exit` is not working at all. OS: Fedora 30, PHP 7.3.

Simple script:

```php
<?php

exit;
exit();
exit(0);
exit(1);
exit("exit");

die;
die();
die(0);
die(1);
die("die");
echo "Hello world\n";
```

Output:

```
$ php check-exit.php 
Hello world
```

Why this happens? How to make `exit` to work as documented?

Comment: try to write `exit()` instead of `exit`

Comment: I can't reproduce that. It works for me

Comment: @Joseph `exit;` can be used without parenthesis, see example 2 at https://php.net/exit

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce it either, so I'm guessing you're executing a different file, or without having saved it.

Comment: Clean your browser cache may be this is the issue

Comment: I start from terminal. Not browser.

Comment: @RobinSingh PHP is a server-side language anyways, so the browser wouldn't really cache anything from it. ;-)

Comment: Try with installing ```xampp``` or any other server and do this with your browser.

Comment: What happens when you run `php -r 'exit; echo "foo\n";'`? If that doesn't produce any output you're not running the file you think you are. Also make sure you don't have any text outside the php tags.

Comment: I removed php-pecl-uopz-6.1.1-1.fc30.x86_64 package from the system. Now works as expected.

Answer (score 6):

Not working `exit` is a side effect of `php-pecl-uopz` package installed on my system. After removing the package the problem is gone. See [uopz_allow_exit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uopz-allow-exit.php) for details.

Comment: In my case package is installed still getting this issue